# Connecting to Rest Server with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

i am trying to make a call to a rest server using jquery/ajax
The rest Server is built in Codeigniter
The ajax function is as follows:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://localhost/projects/comp6300Server/index.php/resources/token//username/" + email + "/password/" + pword + "/institution/" + inst,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
  })
```

The request that is generated is as follows:

```
http://localhost/projects/comp6300Server/index.php/resources/token//username/etambie@yahoo.com/password/qwerty/institution/BCC
```

The status returned is '400 Bad Request'
I think the problem may be with the email that is passed in "etambie@yahoo.com". Is there a way for the ajax automatically convert the '@' to '%40', or would i have to convert all special characters in my strings manually?

Comment: because of `cache=false`. This adds a random timestamp to the string to ensure it's not cached.

Comment: thank you, that clears up this part. I just need to figure out what is wrong with the actual request

Comment: stray semicolon `inst;,` after the variable `inst` could cause that maybe

Comment: just tried it, and adding the semicolon invalidates the jquery. The syntax is as follows:
url: "myurl",
.

Comment: The implication was to remove it, as the string you've shown above contains the semi-colon... Anyway, what's your routing look like? I'm assuming this is something like CodeIgniter

Comment: aah sorry, will edit the question. Yes, i am using the codeigniter framework to build the rest server.

Comment: I mean, the url should get encoded automatically....but if it doesn't, then use `encodeURIComponent()`, and whatever you want to be encoded goes inside.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check out:

1. The "_" parameter is probably added to that each request is unique. If this isn't done, then the browser may attempt to get the result of calling the URL from it's cache, which is probably not what you want.
2. On the bad request ... are you sure you want two slashes after the word 'token' in your url?

Comment: token_get is the name of the rest service i am calling. After that comes the parameters. I tried taking out the second / but it still gives the 400 error